# Reverse Value using Not Operator

Tags: c++, c, operators

I am just want to reverse the binary values of an integer using `NOT ( ~ )` operator but when i were doing like this

```
struct rev
{
        unsigned i:3;  //for only 3 bits means 000 to 111
};
r.i = 5;

printf(" Reverse of %d  =  %u  \n",r.i,~(r.i));
```

it was giving me `Reverse of 5  =  4294967290`

but i want `Reverse of 5 = 2` because i am using 3 bits so if i will do its NOT then 5 will be changed into 2 but it was not showing like this,it was giving me result as `fffffffa` i dont know why.

Means what i want is interchange 1 and 0 only thru NOT operator.
i want

```
0   -   7
1   -   6
2   -   5
```

... like this.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no unsigned:3 type in C, so ~r.i isn't going to only invert 3 bits.

Comment: then how to invert only 3 bits??

Comment: Both syam and Matt already gave you answers. You cannot only invert 3 bits, but you get the equivalent by masking or truncation.

Comment: please, realize, that the code of c/c++ is compiled to assembly and executed with processor. there is nothing like 3bit operations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the stored value of `i` is 3 bits, when you use it for calculations in C or C++, it gets promoted to full size (32 bits, in this case).

You can solve it by :

```
rev r;
rev s;

r.i = 5;
s.i = ~r.i;

printf(" Reverse of %d  =  %u  \n",r.i,s.i);
```

Edit: You could write a class that provides a `uint3`:

```
class uint3
{
  private:
     unsigned val;
     enum { mask = 7; };
  public:
    uint3(unsigned int v = 0) { val = v & mask; }
    uint3 operator=(uint3 v) { val = v.val; return *this; }
    operator int() { return val; }
};

uint3 operator~(uint3 v) { return uint3(~(int)v); }

uint3 r = 5;
printf(" Reverse of %d  =  %u  \n",(int)r, (int(~r)));
```

I haven't compiled the above, but something along those lines.

Comment: this one is ok but why we need second struct here?

Comment: By using a second structure, we force the result to be stored back as a 3-bit. Otherwise, it becomes a 32-bit inverse of the original 3-bit value.

Comment: Is there any other method to force the result to be stored in 3 bits??

Answer (score 1):

`operator~` reverses all the bits of your `unsigned` value (typically, a 32 bits integer).

To limit this to 3 bits you need a bitwise `and` operation in order to apply a bit mask:

```
~variable & 7
```

Comment: but we are having NOT operator to just reverse the bits then why we do this AND with 7.

Comment: @goodies: `operator~` cannot operate on just the 3 (or 5) bits, in order to work, it must use a full integer. If you plan on changing the bitfield size, you can either use MatPetersson's solution (storing the promoted value back into your struct forces the `and` under the hood) or define a static constant for the bitmask in the very same struct so that you don't have magic values (eg. 7) lying everywhere in your code.